# How is Vocab and Integer (one hot) representation stored and what does the ('string', int) tuple means in torchtext.vocab()?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, torchtext

I am trying to train an `RNN` for binary classification. I have my vocab made from 1000000 words and please find the below outputs...

`text_field = torchtext.data.Field(tokenize=word_tokenize)`

```
print(text_field.vocab.freqs.most_common(15))
>>
[('.', 516822), (',', 490533), ('the', 464796), ('to', 298670), ("''", 264416), ('of', 226307), ('I', 224927), ('and', 215722), ('a', 211773), ('is', 180965), ('you', 180359), ('``', 165889), ('that', 156425), ('in', 138038), (':', 132294)]
```

```
print(text_field.vocab.itos[:15])
>>
['<unk>', '<pad>', '.', ',', 'the', 'to', "''", 'of', 'I', 'and', 'a', 'is', 'you', '``', 'that']
```

```
text_field.vocab.stoi
>>
{'<unk>': 0,'<pad>': 1,'.': 2,',': 3,'the': 4,'to': 5,"''": 6,'of': 7,'I': 8,'and': 9,'a': 10, 'is': 11,'you': 12,'``': 13,'that': 14,'in': 15,....................
```

The documentation says:

```
freqs – A collections.Counter object holding the frequencies of tokens in the data used to build the Vocab.
stoi – A collections.defaultdict instance mapping token strings to numerical identifiers.
itos – A list of token strings indexed by their numerical identifiers.
```

Which not comprehensible by me.

**Can Some one Please explain what are these by giving the intuition of each of those**?

For example, if `the` is represented by `4`, then does it mean that if a sentence contains the word `the`,

1. Is it going to be a 1 at location 4?  OR
2. Is it going to be a 1 at position 464796 OR
3. Is it going to be a 4 at position 464796??

What happens when multiple `the` are there there??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "the" is represented by 4, then that means that

- `itos[4]` is "the"
- `stoi["the"]` is 4
- there is a tuple `('the', <count>)` somewhere in `freqs`, where `count` is the number of times that 'the' appears in your input text. That count has nothing to do with its numerical identifier 4.

Comment: So these are not passed in One-Hot encoding form to the RNN?

Comment: Yes, they are. One-hot encoding is just an index in practice.

Comment: No, but if the words are having numerical numering instead of [`0,1]`, aren't they `Label Encoded` instead of `One Hot`??

Comment: You're right, I was using one-hot encoding in a very broad sense. Maybe "label encoded" is a better term, although I'm not super familiar with it.

Comment: Yeah, everywhere it is referred as `One Hot Encoding`. So will a hypothetical sentence such as `you and that in you`  be passed as `[12,9,14,15,12]`? If so, would't it create a bias in the network as the model will read `9<12<14<15` when there is no specific ordering?

Comment: These indices are meant for use in an embedding. So they are not used as numerical continuous variables – doing that would indeed be a bad idea.

Comment: Then what would the above sentence be represented to the first embedding layer given my vocab size=20?

Comment: `[12,9,14,15,12]` like you said.

Comment: But it is the problem. Wouldn't that create bias? or the `Embedding Layer` takes care of that?

Comment: The embedding layer takes care of that. See e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GK1XhPM3K0g&feature=youtu.be&t=540